# What do I do for a feral sick cat?

Tags: cats, feral

I feed a small feral community, this particular little guy is about 6 months old & I noticed for a few days that he was getting sluggish & his eyes were getting crusty, finally about the third day I was able to capture him & took him to the vet. Vet gave him a long lasting shot of antibiotics, diagnosed him with an upper respiratory illness & he tested negative for the “big 3” also vet started him a dewormer for 3 days (he was bloated)  I didn’t notice him eating for a day or so before I was able to trap & now we are third day from vet he’s still not eating on his own & not really standing. I’ve been feeding every 2 hrs (not at night) with a syringe, wet food mixed with water & just started on wet food mixed with kitten milk. It’s the weekend & vet is not open, little guy has urinated only over night still has not had a bowel movement. I’m trying everything I can to save this little guy until the vet opens back up. Is there anything else I could be doing? What do I need to watch for? Thank you